# Why doesn't Javascript "await" wait for the correct amount of time?

Tags: javascript, async-await, for-await

This code doesn't work as expected:

```js
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

function diff(expected) {
  let x = expected - Date.now();
  if (x > 0) {
    return `earlier ${x} ms`;
  } else if (x < 0) {
    return `late ${-x} ms`;
  } else {
    return `just in time`;
  }
}

start = Date.now();
async function demo() {
  let loop_count = 5;
  for (let i = 0; i < loop_count; i++) {
    console.log(diff(start + i * 1000) + `: Waited ${i} seconds...`);
    await sleep(i * 1000);
  }
  console.log(diff(start + loop_count * 1000) + ': Done');
}

demo();
```

Output is:

```
$ node test.js 
just in time: Waited 0 seconds...
earlier 993 ms: Waited 1 seconds...
earlier 993 ms: Waited 2 seconds...
late 10 ms: Waited 3 seconds...
late 2011 ms: Waited 4 seconds...
late 5013 ms: Done
```

Where does this difference come from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Where does this difference come from?

Because you measure it incorrectly. First of all you do `` console.log(diff(start + i * 1000) + `: Waited ${i} seconds...`); `` before the `await sleep(i * 1000);`. This test has to be after the `sleep`.

The other problem is that you don't change the `start` value and that you always use the same `start` value as the reference for each iteration.

So after `i>1` you will get wrong results: You already waited `1` second, so for `i=2` the total time elapsed from `start` is `(1 + 2)` seconds, for `i=3` to total time elapsed from `start` is `(1 + 2 + 3)` seconds, ... .

Updating the code so that the previous seconds slept are also included in the calculation gives the expected result:

```js
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

function diff(expected) {
  let x = expected - Date.now();
  if (x > 0) {
    return `earlier ${x} ms`;
  } else if (x < 0) {
    return `late ${-x} ms`;
  } else {
    return `just in time`;
  }
}

function sumUp(num) {
  let res = 0;
  for(let i=0; i<=num ; i++) {
    res += i;
  }
  return res;
}

start = Date.now();
async function demo() {
  let loop_count = 5;
  for (let i = 0; i < loop_count; i++) {
    await sleep(i * 1000);
    console.log(diff(start + sumUp(i) * 1000) + `: Waited ${i} seconds...`);
  }
  console.log(diff(start + sumUp(loop_count) * 1000) + ': Done');
}

demo();
```

The result will always be `late` because `setTimeout` will wait for **at least** the given amount of time. And for the way you measure that error will pile up for each called timer.

Comment: Upps, it turns out I wrote `sleep(i * 1000)` instead of  `sleep(1000)`. What a shame.